# Double-click this warning

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have just started working with Xamarin this week.  I created a new "[Mobile App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started/)" in Azure and downloaded from Azure a sample Xamarin Forms app.  When I try opening it in Xamarin Studio, I get this message:

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.  In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file...

There are two problems with this message.  First, these warnings exist only in Xamarin Studio.  The same solution opened in Visual Studio 2015 does not have this warning - and so it is not possible for me to "double-click" it in Visual Studio.

Second, the full text of this Xamarin Studio warning is virtually inaccessible because there is no way to copy it.  What portion of the warning you see above, I had to transcribe.  The rest of the warning is VERY long, and Xamarin Studio is acting as if it expects me to copy it somehow.  But the only way to copy it...is again to spend twenty or thirty minutes transcribing it.  Certainly I must be misunderstanding how to use Xamarin Studio.  Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Is there a Xamarin Studio keyboard shortcut or trick that would allow me to capture this warning?  And is it normal for Xamarin Studio to request problems to be fixed through Visual Studio?  Why does the warning not exist in Visual Studio?

This solution also doesn't build in Visual Studio 2015.  I don't get any warnings (unfortunately?), and in fact I don't appear to have any build errors either.  However, when it attempts to deploy (Windows phone emulation) it gives me a variety of errors.  Most of them are of this variety:

> The name 'X' does not exist in the current context.

I'm baffled by this, because the symbols it names are indeed missing.  So why does it build successfully?

Comment: I get these errors as well, though in Visual Studio. Normally its a NuGet package having one version of the DLL and your project referencing another. In Forms particularly there are issues with referencing those DLL's, specifically, Threading and Runtime. However they don't cause any issues in build or runtime.

Could you please list out a few of the symbols it can't seem to find, it might help source the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem in visual studio or xamarin studio.

If the device on which you are trying to deploy the build,already has an apk file installed(not from your work station), you will get this issue.

To resolve this uninstall it from the device and also from the package manager and then try to deploy the build.
I hope it will help.